# My Moment time is changing during Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, momentjs

I have a dispatch function (in event_actions.js) being called from a component:

```
export function moveEvent( event, start) 
{  
    let startEv = event.start  // moment obj
    let endEv = event.end  // moment obj
    let diff = endEv.diff(startEv)  
    console.log("time diff", diff)  // time diff 7200000
    let newstart = moment(start, "YYYYMMDDHHmm")  
    console.log("newstart", newstart)  // newstart 2017-06-14T06:00:00-04:00 
    console.log("newend", newstart.add(diff, 'milliseconds').format()) // newend 2017-06-14T08:00:00-04:00
    let payload = {
        start: newstart,
        end: newstart.add(diff, 'milliseconds'),
        id: event.id,
    }      

    return { type: 'MOVE_EVENT', payload: payload }
}
```

And here is my 'MOVE_EVENT' case from event_reducer.js:

```
case 'MOVE_EVENT': {
    console.log("eventstart",action.payload.start.format())  // eventstart 2017-06-14T10:00:00-04:00
    console.log("eventend",action.payload.end.format())  //  eventend 2017-06-14T10:00:00-04:00
    console.log(state.events) // prints all events including the one I'm moving which already has the bad values for start and end

    let eventIndex = state.events.findIndex(event => event.id === action.payload.id)
    let newEvent = state.events[eventIndex]            
    newEvent.start = action.payload.start
    newEvent.end = action.payload.end

    return Object.assign( {}, 
        state, { 
            events: [
                ...state.events.slice(0, eventIndex), 
                newEvent,
                ...state.events.slice(eventIndex + 1),
            ] 
        }
    )
}
```

The comments is what is being printed out by the console.logs.  The dates being printed from event_actions.js are correct.

I also notice when I print out state.events the bad values are already in my state.  How is it possible for my state to be updated before my case even returns anything?

ANSWER:
moment(newstart).add(diff, 'milliseconds')

I'm still not sure how my state changed before the return, but cloning the moment object worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
  start: newstart,
  end: newstart.add(diff, 'milliseconds'),
```

The `add` function changes the date: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

## Fix

Use `clone` before mutating : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I didn't catch the mutable part of the doc.  I was able to fix like this:  moment(newstart).add(diff, 'milliseconds')